# pass variable through initialize function inside addDomListener method

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

[Google maps v3 api suggest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?hl=nl#DomEvents) loading the initialize function using the addDomListener() method instead of attaching it to the body tag.

```
<script>
  function initialize() {
    // Map initialization
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
not:
<body onload="initialize()">
```

But, I would like to pass a variable through the initialize function: f.e. initialize(37). This only works using the body onload method, not via the addDomListener method.

Here's my question: can I do this using the addDomListener method. To put it simpler, following doesn't work, how can I make it work?

```
<script>
    function initialize(countryID) {
        // Map initialization
        // Do stuff with countryID
    }
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize(37));
</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use a anonymous function:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){initialize(37);});
```

Comment: You can also pass variables like this `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',function(){ initialize(marker) });` so then your function will look like this `function initialize(marker){`